# BibTeX related, searched many posts but couldn't find precise answer

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've perused quite a few posts on here and haven't found a precise answer to this, though there are many similar questions.

I am using TexMaker and trying to produce a list of references at the end of my document. Here's basically what I have:

In file.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
text
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

In refs.bib (stolen from another example; my .bib file is exported so I'm fairly certain the syntax is right).

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
   author = "Nobody Jr",
   title = "My Article",
   year = "2006" }
```

I have tried several methods of compiling including latex bibtex latex pdflatex pdfViewer, among others. TexMaker finds no errors, but I get warnings at all of my citations: citation  on page # is undefined. A .bbl file is produced, but it is empty (literally no text whatsoever). My .blg file also appears to have no information in it whatsoever. One of the strangest things (IMO) is that TexMaker KNOWS that my citations exist because if I type \cite I get auto completions which match my citations.

I'm pretty new to using LaTeX so I'm don't assume I have tried something obvious, I probably haven't, though I HAVE tried pretty much everything that I found posted online...

Comment: Your `file.tex` doesn't include a `\cite` command ... ? And what package are you using for citing things? Usually people use `natbib` or `cite`, I think. This should then work fine if you compile with the following compilation sequence: `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: You are not citing the reference in your example.  Without a `\cite{Nobody06}`, how is LaTeX/BibTeX to know that you expect to see Nobody show up in the bibliography?  (It is also good practice, I think, to avoid spaces after the `@misc{` ... i.e., write `@misc{Nobody06, ...<rest of entry>...}`.

Comment: @Adam Note that you don't *need* to load a package for reference management. That said, you forgot `biblatex` `;)`

Comment: @SeanAllred Fair point. I didn't realize `\cite` was defined in LaTeX2e. And yes ... I plan to try to make the switch this summer ... `:)`

Comment: @cruseyd: The accepted answer to [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number) should be helpful

Comment: You might try adding `\nocite{*}` just before your call to `\biographystyle`.  This should automatically cite all references that are in your bib-file.